# Assistance with writing PowerShell script to search Active Directory for a machine name

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm writing a script to automate some AWS-launched Windows server instances.
I've got the DNS changes, and the join-domain part okay, but I'm having trouble iterating the namespace...for example;

machine is spun up with auto-generated name: WIN-JDK2349DFJR
I want the script to check AD and see if the name, say, imagesN, is in use, and if it is, to name the machine imagesN+1.

Server spins up, with auto name (WIN-JDK2349DFJR). 
The script invokes-
Script checks AD: Three servers are named "images1, images2, images3"
The script changes the DNS to the local DC, changes the name to "images4", joins the domain, and reboots.

I'm not sure how to write a PowerShell script to check for the machine name imageN in Active Directory and increment N if a machine account with N exists in Active Directory with the name imageN.

Comment: What have you written so far to perform the "lookup, check for images1..N, and increment" bit? Which parts of that are working? Which are not?

Comment: Keep in mind, Windows computer name changes don't take effect until after a reboot. So if you rename *and* domain join without rebooting first, the computer will get joined to AD with the old name.

Comment: So you know I did test my answer on a Windows Server 2012 DC.

Comment: So, the AWS SSM allows me to push scripts out to machines as part of their creation- I'm also using an AD connector in my VPC to ensure that I have DNS resolution and AD access from inside the private-subnet on the VPC. When you spin up an instance, you can pass a bunch of variables and scripts to the image via SSM, and that's the plan. I've created two diff OUs for the <images> and <mongo> machines, and each OU will have their own iterated machine names. So, the script can process the <rename><reboot><join domain><reboot> order just fine, and it's all hands-off

Comment: https://github.com/illiumrex/LocalR/blob/master/MAster1.ps1

Answer (score 1):

Troy,

I think there are some problems from an order of operations point of view.

The answer to your question ("trouble iterating the namespace") is answered below. After my answer you will see why I think you are going to have other problems.

**Answer to how you write a PowerShell script to iterate namespace.**

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$counter = 0
$nameselected = "no"
$server = "image$counter"
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Do { 
    Write-Host "Checking for existance of $server."
    if (Get-ADComputer -Identity $server) {
    Write-Host "Count is $counter."
    $global:counter++
    $server = "image$counter"
    Write-Host "New count is $counter."
    }
}
Until ( ( -not $( Get-ADComputer -Identity $server)) )
    $nameslected = "yes"
    Write-Host "The name will be $server."
    Write-Host "Replace this line with the with your function for changing DNS or joining the domain."
```

https://github.com/4D5A/Custom-PowerShell/blob/master/Scripts/Microsoft%20Active%20Directory/Get-AvailableComputerName.ps1

**Likely problems you are going to have trying to do this.**

1. You must change the name of the computer before you join the computer to the domain.
2. You must restart the computer after you change the computer name before you join the computer to the domain.
3. To run the PowerShell script the computer needs to have .NET Framework 3.5.1 installed https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg413289.aspx
4. You describe a process of running this PowerShell script on a computer that is not joined to the domain. A possible solution to this is by using Remote PowerShell to a computer that is joined to the domain and does have .NET Framework 3.5.1 installed and does have RSAT installed and then getting the available computer name from that PowerShell session and using it on the local computer in a local PowerShell session.

Comment: How exactly does the member client perform the `Import-Module Active Directory` before its been joined to the domain? The OP's question goes: 1. changes the DNS to the local DC, 2. changes the name to "images4", 3. joins the domain, 4 reboot.

Comment: The order of the OP's question doesn't work for multiple reasons (including the reason Ryan pointed out). My answer also doesn't take into account the fact that the computer would need to install .Net and RSAT for it to be able to use 'import-module ActiveDirectory'. What the OP is trying to do as originally asked simply won't work. My answer does however address the part of the question about how to query AD for imageN and increment N if imageN exists which I think will give the OP he information he needs provided he rethinks the order of how he performs the swipe rate steps.

Comment: Editing your answer to include those very details would improve it greatly. :)

Comment: Here's what I have, adding the above scripting. REMEMBER: this is being passed to the machine via AWS-SSM, which *doesn't* require Remote-PS subsystems...and the .NET and Import-Module pieces are built into the AMI, so I don't have to do any additional config there.

Comment: https://github.com/illiumrex/LocalR/blob/master/MAster1.ps1

Comment: You will want to have `$computername = $server` and not `$computername = Read-Host`.